# Creating a "Hejri" calendar in Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight

Does anybody know how to create an Islamic Hejri calendar in Silverlight? I have done tons of research but found nothing.

Comment: Do you want to create a visual representation of the calendar or do you want to do date computations using the calendar?

Comment: I actually wan to make a visual represntation, 10x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`HijriCalendar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.hijricalendar%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class. It is available in Silverlight.